# Gnuplot graph lines overlap and can't be seen

Tags: gnuplot

This the data of the 3 files I want to plot:

file1

```
 01:12:06 90000
 01:12:07 30000
 01:12:17 30000
 01:12:27 30000
 01:12:37 30000
 01:12:47 30000
 01:12:57 30000
 01:13:07 30000
 01:13:17 30000
 01:13:27 30000
 01:13:37 30000
 01:13:47 90000
 01:13:57 30000
 01:14:07 30000
```

file2

```
 01:12:02 90000
 01:12:07 30000
 01:12:17 30000
 ...
 01:18:47 90000
 01:18:57 90000
```

file3

```
 01:12:04 90000
 01:12:07 30000
 01:12:17 30000
 ...
 01:15:37 45000
 01:15:47 45000
```

These are the commands I'm using to plot the graph:

```
 gnuplot> set xdata time; set timefmt '%H:%M:%S';
 gnuplot> set format x "%H:%M:%S" 
 gnuplot> set xlabel "time"; 
          set ylabel "Data rates"; 
          set grid;
          set xrange ["01:12:04" : "01:18:57"];
          set yrange ["0" : "100000"];
          set style data linespoints; 
          plot "file1" using 1:2 title "connection-1", "file2" using 1:2 title "connection-2", "file3" using 1:2 title "connection-3
```

and this is the graph generated:
[image]

As you can see file1 has points ranging for period 01:12:06 to 01:14:07 but the graph doesn't show all the points from file1. This is true for file3 also. Either the plot lines are overlapping or gnuplot is discarding all this data. I want to see 3 lines for the 3 files.

Comment: Have you tried plotting them in a different order?

Comment: Try `plot "file1" using 1:2 title "connection-1" lw 6, "file2" using 1:2 title "connection-2", "file3" using 1:2 title "connection-3"` NB I have added a LARGE line width specification to the possibly overdrawn line.

Comment: @gboffi adding LARGE lines showed that the plots are indeed present but have overlapped and hidden each other. Is there a way I can stack these lines like Excel does?

Comment: What do you mean by "stack lines like Excel does"?

Comment: I mean that the lines have some space (vertically) between them. I just want to be able to see them separately.

Comment: I see, then accept the answer that gives the recipe for that (not mine...)

Comment: @user1071840 If you just want to see them separately you can use `multiplot`: for example `set multiplot layout 3,1` and then use three separate instances of `plot`: `plot "file1" using 1:2 title "connection-1"; plot "file2" using 1:2 title "connection-2"; plot "file3" using 1:2 title "connection-3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that gnuplot overwrite the 1st line with the third, I see different possibilities (or combination of possibilities)

1. assign different line widths (larger to thinner), or
2. assign different colors (lightier to darker) to your lines, or
3. assign different sizes to the markers (in this case I'd advise circle markers), or
4. add a different, small shift to the lines.

I dislike, just a bit, point 4 because it's against the Holyness of Data, but we are amoral guys, aren't we?

I promise that, when I'll understand what is the solution that Excel uses, I'll try to update my answer.

#### Edit

Point 2, I realize it now, doesn't represent an indipendent solution to our problem, but works well when applied in ccoperation with line or marker widths.

Answer (score 0):

As said, the dots of line no. 3 consist of a '+' and an 'x' , so they hide points of line no 1 ('+') and 2 ('x')

You can choose other point markers. Use the command `test` to get an overview of available styles.

For example,

```
plot ... pointtype 4,\
     ... pointtype 6,\
     ... pointtype 8
```

The first uses squares, the second circles and the third triangles.

According to the comments: It is not possible to shift the lines artificially. But you may add a constant to the values:

```
plot "file1" using 1:($2+10) with linespoints pointtype 4   # shift all y-values by 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I plotted first the dataset with the greatest overlap. Then I plotted the dataset with the next greatest overlap e.t.c.. In this way, lines with less overlap are drawn above lines with greater overlap (longer lines).
In particular this is my file:

```
1, 0.50000000023514612479
2, 0.50000000002351452366

1, 0.50000000023514612479
2, 0.50000000002351452366
3, 0.50000000000235200748

1, 0.50000000023514612479
2, 0.50000000002351452366
3, 0.50000000000235200748
4, 0.50000000000023503421

1, 0.50000000023514612479
2, 0.50000000002351452366
3, 0.50000000000235200748
4, 0.50000000000023503421
5, 0.50000000000001576517

1, 0.50000000023514612479
2, 0.50000000002351452366
3, 0.50000000000235200748
4, 0.50000000000023503421
5, 0.50000000000001576517
6, 0.50000000000000022204
```

The plot command:

```
plot "file.txt" index 4 with linespoints title "alpha:1e-05" , \
     "file.txt" index 3 with linespoints title "alpha:1e-04",\
     "file.txt" index 2 with linespoints title "alpha:1e-03",\
     "file.txt" index 1 with linespoints title "alpha:1e-02",\
     "file.txt" index 0 with linespoints title "alpha:1e-01"
```

Then you can use different line widths to differentiate between lines.